# Connecting to SQL Server from Tomcat using client credentials

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, jdbc, windows-authentication

I'm developing a web application that preferably should use the clients credentials (windows user) to connect to an SQL Server.

The reason for this is to have per user auditing on the database access, and it should preferably be based on the AD to avoid several logins and also make administration easy.

The application runs on Tomcat 7.0.57 and have SpnegoHttpFilter set up, and I can get the user name and user principal from the request. And I can connect to the SQL server using the Tomcat's Window user.

BUT how do I go about connecting to SQL Server using the clients user credentials (just a username is not enough of course)?

Will getting the delegated credential from the DelegateServiceRequest help (it is not set up currently)? I have not found any support for using GSSCredential in the Microsoft JDBC driver (some searches indicates that the Progress DataDirect JDBC Driver have support for using GSSCredential but I have yet to find any documentation on how to do this, and I would prefer to use a free solution if available).

I have searched for answers to this but so far I haven't come up with any good clues on how to proceed, any ideas?

NOTE: This is in a corporate environment which means that all users are managed via the AD, including access to the database and windows login.

NOTE 2: The following solution seems to work

The connection string looks like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<bdname>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;
```

When creating the connection, the code looks like:

```
DelegateServletRequest dsr = (DelegateServletRequest)HttpServletRequest();
GSSCredential cred = dsr.getDelegatedCredential();

try
{
    Subject s = GSSUtil.createSubject(cred.getName(), cred);
    return (Connection) Subject.doAs(s,
            new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>()
            {
                @Override
                public Object run() throws Exception
                {
                    Connection c = null;
                    c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    return c;
                }
            });
}
catch (PrivilegedActionException e)
{
    throw new DAOException(e);
}
catch (GSSException e)
{
    throw new DAOException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not a best practice. In a web application database connections should not depend on the web application user's login. Using application user login as database login causes multiple issues:

- If your web application has 10000 users you have to create all those 10000 users in the database. If your web application has user creation feature then application should run with database admin credentials to be able to add users to the database. Running the web app with database admin credentials is a major security risk.
- Creating a database user for every web application user is going to shoot up your database license costs in most of the commercial databases because they charge you by user licenses (apart from other criteria they may have for calculating license cost).
- You cannot configure connection pool because pool configuration is a pre-configuration which does not depend on the currently logged-in web application user. Not having a connection pool can significantly degrade your web application performance.

Summary is - it is a bad idea to use application user credentials for connecting to the database.

There are other ways of auditing database access. Most of the databases allow you to set some kind of session information on the database connection for this purpose. You can access that in your audit logging code to log which application user did what operations on the database. For example:

- In postgresql you can use a GUC variable to identify the web application user acting on the database. Log that variable in the audit logs to know which web application user did what actions on the database.
- In Oracle you can use what is called as client identifier. Google for more information.

Other databases should have something equivalent. Please google.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for the connection pool

Comment: This is in a corporate environment and the active directory is used for all user management (including database access to the SQL Server and computer login). This means that there is no need to create users in the database for this application.

I do agree on the problem with connection pooling, that is an issue. But apart from that I don't see how to implement a single-sign-on solution without using the web application users login.

Comment: Why do you need to use single sign-on to connect to the database?  You can try to dismiss as many of the downsides as you can and convince yourself the remaining downsides are not a big deal.  But what is the advantage to doing this?

Comment: The active directory is used for user management, both for windows login, UN*X login and various authentication/authorization settings.

For this particular project, SQL Server has been selected as the database to use for several reasons, one of them being that it can use windows authentication for login and privileges in the database which makes user management easier and uniform.

Using single-sign-on makes it easy for the users (no extra login) and user management is uniform and centralized.

Comment: Single-sign-on (SSO) and application's database authentication credentials are very different things. I don't understand why you are trying to tie them together. Remember - DBA manages database users and a sys admin manages system users. How will tying them up simplify user management? It may look like it is simple in an environment with very few users. It will be a nightmare as number of users grow. You should seriously think about changing the approach.

Comment: Both DBA and sys admin use the same AD to manage the users. There is one set of users in the AD that the DBA can give different database credentials (since SQL Server use the same AD for credentials).

And the number of users are very few for this application.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments it looks like @Rico is stubborn on the approach (which can invite lot of misery in future). Believing you know what you are doing this is one way (there can be other ways too) how you "can" do it. If you feel like doing it even after you read the whole story please feel free to go ahead and implement:

- You should use AD credentials for web application authentication. So far I have got the impression that it is the case - you are using AD credentials for web application authentication. You have to cache these credentials for database authentication later. Following points will tell you how to do that.
- If you are using a web authentication framework for authentication figure out whether the authentication framework or the web application framework allows you to put a hook into authentication mechanism to get AD credentials and cache it for authenticating database connections. For example - a good authentication framework should have pre and post authentication hook/callbacks/listeners allowing you to access the credentials. If that is not possible you can use a web filter to intercept the authentication request to cache posted credentials. Figure out what works best for you.

  - If you cannot hook into the authentication framework or cannot use any other means of intercepting the authentication request you will have to change the authentication mechanism and do authentication on your own. If you are authenticating on your own you get the credentials directly and you can cache it. But remember - authentication is not a very trivial activity. Be aware of all the security implications of it when you write your own authentication code.
- On successful authentication cache the credentials in the server side session (`javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`) so that every request has access to it. There are security implications of this. This cached credentials can be revealed to attackers/hackers by mistake or by design of attackers.
- From the question it looks like the place where you are establishing database connection has access to `HttpServletRequest`. Call `HttpServletRequest.getSession` method on the request object to get the session and retrieve the credentials from it. Establish database connection using retrieved credentials.

  - It looks like your application does not use a connection pool. That is very inefficient because establishing a new database connection is pretty expensive process. This new approach does not make any difference in that department. It will continue to be as inefficient as it was in the code you mentioned in your question.

From the question it looks like following situation does not exist in  your application. If at all any of them exist this is what you have to do:

- If your application uses connection pool for efficiency: You will have to throw out the connection pool because pre-configured pooled connections cannot change the credentials when you request a connection from the pool. You will have to establish a new connection using the credentials cached in `HttpSession` every time when you need a connection. It will be very inefficient, but that is what you have bargained for.
- If your application uses an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) tool:Typically ORMs use a pre-configured connection pool for efficiency. Figure out whether you can inject a new connection into the ORM for every HTTP request. If the ORM does not allow that throw out the ORM too. Be prepared to handle all database interactions on your own.

Duh .. do you still feel it is worth doing?

Comment: As You can see in my code example, I get the credentials directly from the request (using SPNEGO and delegated credentials), so there is no need for me to store the credentials in the session, at least not for this particular purpose.

The connection to the SQL server (using the connection string shown) will use these credentials to authenticate (and authorize) the user using the AD for the database access.

Your point about connection pooling is noted and a valid point, however in this application I think it will be manageable (few users and not very intense database access).